# Curiosity on system device nomenclature - Gaussian Mixture Models

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture

Would not know if this is the best SE website to ask, but I could not find anything better, especially because the answer might involve a fair amount of computer science (although this is an hypothesis).

I hold a MSc. in Statistics, and thus have extensively explored Gaussian Mixture Models. That's why, upon buying my brand new Lenovo E580 laptop (Windows 10 Pro x64), I was surprised to find, under the System devices drop down menu in the Device Manager, a reference to GMMs (although I'm not sure what the actual item is pointing to). I have included a picture to clarify the point.

[image]

**Questions**

1) What is the highlighted item referring to?

2) How do GMMs have anything to do with this?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. It could be a good question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @dkaeae I can see where you're coming from, as the question is presented as being a question about the operation of a commercially available system. But I think there's an implicit question of "What do modern computer systems use GMMs for that's so important it needs hardware acceleration?" is just about on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

These are accelerators for Gaussian Mixture Modelling used for speech recognition and video processing applications.  They can be typically accessed via openCL libraries.

GMMs are used for efficient classification of partial or noisy data e.g. speaker voices or people object in videos.